# Unable to get return value from async function , await not working as expected (Vue API Service)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I am trying to create a service to communicate with my API, I am not quite familiar with async/await but I am facing the following problem and according to what I have read in the documentation doesn't make much sense.

If I try to use await to get the result from an async function (UserAuthService.login) it gives me an error saying:
" 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function"

The error happens in the component Login when I try to get the result, the "login" function works fine if the login function is an async function why I am getting this error? How can I get then the result from the async function?

auth_user_service.ts:

```
const UserAuthService = {
  /**
     * Login the user and store the access token to TokenService.
     *
     * @returns success
    **/
  login: async function (email: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const requestData = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'auth/token/',
      header: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
      data: {
        client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.VUE_APP_APPLICATION_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: email,
        password: password,
        scope: 'read write'
      }
    }

    try {
      const response = await ApiService.customRequest(requestData) // just return axios(data);


      if (response.status == 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  },
}
```

Login.vue:

```
<template>...</template>
<script lang="ts">

import { UserAuthService } from '../services/auth/auth_user.service'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        form: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
    }),
    methods: {
        login():void {
            let success: boolean = await UserAuthService.login(this.form.email, this.form.password); //error here
            console.log(success)

        }
    } 
};
</script>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest",
      "vuetify"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to make your `login` component method an async function in order to use `await` within it

Comment: @Phil you are right, thank you so much. I was stuck on this during 2h...

Comment: @Phil which version of Vue and lint program are you using? I am using vetur for visual code but is working kind of bad to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `await` inside the method, you must declare it as `async`:

```
methods: {
    async login(): Promise<void> { // added async, changed return type
        let success: boolean = await UserAuthService.login(this.form.email, this.form.password);
        console.log(success)
    }
}
```

Also notice that due to the `async` keyword, the method now returns a `Promise`. Because you are using TypeScript, you must change its returning type from `void` to `Promise<void>` as well.